# Finding coefficients and adding text

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

I want to find the coefficients in the loop and add the text.
This coefficient may change. For example: 10, 5, 3 ...
I would like the system to find these coefficients and add text according to the coefficient I set

```
$coefficient=10; 
$start=100; 
$end=200;
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){ 
    echo $i.'<br>';
}
```

example;
110 .. text, 120...text, 130...text
or 
$coefficient=5; 105...text, 110...text, 115...text 
I want to find coefficients and add text

Comment: Sounds like you want `$i+=$coefficient` rather than `$i++`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple modulus math.

```
$coefficient=10; 
$start=100; 
$end=200;
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){ 
    if($i % $coefficient == 0) // if (i / coefficient) has a remainder of 0
    {
        echo $i . "...text";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why perform 100 iterations when only 10 are needed? Better use `$i += $coefficient` as suggested above by @MarkBaker.

Comment: I agree with Mark. Mark should submit an answer. Here is my answer.

And as you can see, my answer is not Mark's. That's why SO allows multiple answers :)

Comment: Do you think this is better in terms of performance? ($i+=coef..)

Comment: @ismail Mark's is by far the more logical and efficient solution. But as you can see I gave it in the format OP was requesting.

Comment: I understand... @SanchkeDellowar thank you all for your help.